# Insert Equation Parameter Values in Tables

Tags: tables, nomenclature

Is it possible to create a table in LateX that would fill in with the values from some parameters used in the Equations throughout the text?.

Just to be clear, something like nomenclature, where you can define the symbol and you can print it in a nomenclature section, but this time a table with values (e.g. `\command{x}{5}{mm}`, which would create a row with | x | 5 | mm |)

To make myself even clearer, please see the following example:

---

Let's say we have the following equation:

**ax + b = 0**

and I would like to have the values a and b defined in a table. If possible I would like to have something like this:

```
\command{a}{100}{mm}
\command{b}{10}{mm}
```

And this would index a table that would look like this:

```
|Parameter | Value | Unit |
--------------------------- 
|a         | 100   | mm   |    
|b         | 10    | mm   |
```

The entries in this table could then be referenced in the text according to some key associated with each entry, i.e. `\printval{a}` would print "100", `\printunit{b}` would print "mm".

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This should be possible, but `equations` are not meant to be evalutated -- they are typeset. And `TeX` commands usually start with `\\` not with `/`

Comment: Have a look at the `pgfplotstable` package.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, thank you for the comment. I have edited that. It's not the equations that I want to evaluate. I would like to define the symbols outside of the equation class. You can even forget about the equations. Let's say I want to define random letters throughout the text and I want those letters to be centralized in a table at the beginning of the text. 

JPi, thank you as well. The *pdfplotstable* looks like the first step to write a code for what I need.

Comment: It's still a little unclear to me - what is the functionality you wish to access that constructing a table by hand wouldn't give you?  Do you want to use something like the `\ac{}` from the acro/acronym packages - if so how?

Comment: @DaiBowen, it's the same as the nomenclature. You can write the nomenclature manually, but the package nomencl (or others) makes it easier to keep track of the symbols. I want to define each parameter below the equation and next to it, I want the value, so I am sure that I have all the values in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Alternate answer which uses `expl3`

This example with `expl3` uses `\newparam[$]{alpha}{\alpha}{1.3}{kg}` defines a parameter saved with a key "alpha", which prints as `\alpha` with value `1.3` and units `kg`.  The optional `[$]` places `$` around the parameter in the printed list.  `\param{key}`, `\paramval{key}` and `\paramunits{key}` print the parameter, value and units associated with "key".  The key must consist of letters only, but the printed param can include math elements like `\alpha` or `x_i`.

The list of parameters is printed by `\printparams`, this checks to see if a parameter has been called and only parameters called by one of `\param`, `\paramval` or `\paramunits`.  In this code `\printparams` should be enclosed in some `tabular` environment as it just prints `$\alpha$ & 1.3 & kg \\` for a parameter defined as `\newparam[$]{alpha}{\alpha}{1.3}{kg}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_param_used_seq
\seq_new:N \l_param_printlist_seq

\NewDocumentCommand{\newparam}{O{}mmmm}
{
    \cs_new:cn {param_enclose_#2:}{#1}
    \cs_new:cn {param_param_#2:}{#3}
    \cs_new:cn {param_value_#2:}{#4}
    \cs_new:cn {param_units_#2:}{#5}
    \bool_new:c {l_param_#2_used_bool}
}

\cs_new:Nn \param_lookup:nn {
    \use:c {param_#1_#2:} 
    \bool_if:cF {l_param_#2_used_bool}
    {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_param_used_seq { #2 }
    }
    \bool_set_true:c {l_param_#2_used_bool}
}

\NewDocumentCommand \printparams { }
{
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_param_used_seq
    {
        \seq_put_right:Nn \l_param_printlist_seq
        {
            \use:c {param_enclose_##1:} \param_lookup:nn{param}{##1} \use:c {param_enclose_##1:} & \param_lookup:nn{value}{##1} & \param_lookup:nn{units}{##1} \\
        }
    }
    \seq_use:Nn \l_param_printlist_seq { }
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\param}{m}{ \param_lookup:nn{param}{#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\paramval}{m}{ \param_lookup:nn{value}{#1} }
\NewDocumentCommand{\paramunits}{m}{ \param_lookup:nn{units}{#1} }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newparam[$]{x}{x_ i}{10}{mm}
\newparam{length}{L}{13.2}{km}
\newparam[$]{alpha}{$\alpha$}{1.3}{kg}

\begin{document}

Parameter: $\param{x}$
Value: \paramval{x}
Units: \paramunits{x}

\begin{equation}
\param{length}=1320000\param{x}
\end{equation}

The length \param{length} is \paramval{length}\paramunits{length}

Here are the parameters:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ c  c  c }
Parameter & Value & Units \\ \hline
\printparams \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

This produces

[image: Code example]

### Original answer which uses datatool

This has limitations for saving maths like `\alpha` or `x_i` but for simple strings this should be functional.

As I understand it the datatool package could suit your needs, this is by no means a well developed or intelligent approach - if you look through the glossaries or datatool (or similar) package documentation you may well find a better way to do this.

The example below defines a table with columns holding a key, parameter, value and units.  Entries are added using `\newparam{length}{L}{13.2}{km}` the parameter, value and units respectively for the parameter with a key "length" are `\param{length}`, `\paramval{length}` and `\paramunits{length}`.

`\printparamtable` prints the table of all parameters saved.  No check is made as to whether the parameter defined by `\newparam` is actually used in the text - everything added with a `\newparam` is printed.

The preamble defines the macros above which are likely the form you want to use in terms of the underlying datatool macros.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{longtable}

\newcommand{\paramtable}{ParameterLookUp}
\DTLnewdb{\paramtable}

\newcommand{\paramaddcolumn}[2]{
\DTLaddcolumn{\paramtable}{#1}
\DTLsetheader{\paramtable}{#1}{#2}
}

\paramaddcolumn{paramkey}{Parameter Key}
\paramaddcolumn{param}{Parameter}
\paramaddcolumn{value}{Value}
\paramaddcolumn{units}{Units}

\newcommand{\newparam}[4]{
\DTLnewrow{\paramtable}
\DTLnewdbentry{\paramtable}{paramkey}{#1}
\DTLnewdbentry{\paramtable}{param}{#2}
\DTLnewdbentry{\paramtable}{value}{#3}
\DTLnewdbentry{\paramtable}{units}{#4}
}

\newcommand{\param}[1]{\DTLfetch{\paramtable}{paramkey}{#1}{param}}
\newcommand{\paramval}[1]{\DTLfetch{\paramtable}{paramkey}{#1}{value}}
\newcommand{\paramunits}[1]{\DTLfetch{\paramtable}{paramkey}{#1}{units}}

\newcommand{\printparamtable}{\DTLdisplaylongdb[omit=paramkey]{\paramtable}}

\newparam{x}{x}{10}{mm}
\newparam{length}{L}{13.2}{km}

\begin{document}
Parameter: \param{x}
Value: \paramval{x}
Units: \paramunits{x}

\printparamtable

The length \param{length} is \paramval{length}\paramunits{length}

\begin{equation}
\param{length}=1320000\param{x}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: One more question. What should I add/modify in order to get subscripts or symbols, such as x_i, or \alpha? 

I tried it both with $$ and without and I have an error.

Comment: You're right, I fear that this is just a limitation of my approach.  Objects like `_` can be escaped in datatool with `\_` but these then seem to print as underscores when later called; and it might be possible to just save `\alpha` as alpha and use a slightly different way of calling the parameter with `\csname` to make it function like `\alpha` but I can't immediately put that together.  I'll have a look around and edit if I can come up with any fixes.

Comment: @Paul see my edit for a different strategy which should overcome this problem and allow for the likes of `\alpha` and `x_i`